# How to use boost date facets to parse strings which may not have leading zeros?

Tags: c++, parsing, date, boost, normalization

I'd like to use several `boost::date_facet` variations in C++03 to normalize some string input which can have a variety of different U.S. style formats, for example:

- Feb. 04, 2012
- Feb 04, 2012
- February 04, 2012
- Feb. 4, 2012
- Feb 4, 2012
- February 4, 2012
- 02/04/2012
- 2/04/2012
- 02/4/2012
- 2/4/2012

The issue that I'm running into is how to create a `date_facet` which does not require a leading zero on the month or day.  I see in the Boost documentation of the flags these entries:

```
%d   - Day of the month as decimal 01 to 31
%e # - Like %d, but a leading zero is replaced by a space
%m   - Month name as a decimal 01 to 12
```

So I don't see how to create a facet with no leading zero on month nor one with no leading zero on day (and not an extra space).

How can I do this with Boost?

Comment: Sorry - I thought my implementation would not suffer from the shortcoming you mention. It turns out it does, and now I'm interested in fixing it.